# Converting a networkx 2D graph into a 3D interactive graph

Tags: python, graph, plotly, networkx

I have the following graph in `networkx`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, weight = 1)
G.add_edge(2, 3, weight = 3)
G.add_edge(4, 5, weight = 2)
G.add_edge(6, 3, weight = 4)
G.add_edge(6, 4, weight = 6)


plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
edges = G.edges()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k = 0.5) # k regulates the distance between nodes
weights = [G[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='skyblue', font_weight='bold',  width=weights, pos=pos)
```

Is there a way to convert this 2D graph into a 3D one? The coordinates don't matter. I'm only interested in the ability of the plot to be interactive (i.e. for me to be able to rotate the graph). I know that `plotly` has the ability to do such [plots](https://plotly.com/python/v3/3d-network-graph/), but I'm not sure how to combine my 2D `networkx` graph and `plotly` in such way

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I am not an expert on networkx by any means, so [this article](https://deepnote.com/article/3d-network-visualisations-in-deepnote/) was extremely valuable in answering your question. I have adapted to code to fit your example as best as I can.

We first want to set the parameter `dim=3` when calling `nx.spring_layout` to ensure your coordinates are in 3D. We then extract the x, y, z coordinates of all of the nodes and edges and pass them via traces to the `go.Scatter3d` method in Plotly.

Update: to add weights in the hovertext, we can anchor them to the midpoints between the edges, as described [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/show-edge-weight-in-network-graph/26733).

```
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, weight = 1)
G.add_edge(2, 3, weight = 3)
G.add_edge(4, 5, weight = 2)
G.add_edge(6, 3, weight = 4)
G.add_edge(6, 4, weight = 6)

edge_weights =[1,3,2,4,6]

Num_nodes = len(G.nodes)

# plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
edges = G.edges()

# ## update to 3d dimension
spring_3D = nx.spring_layout(G, dim = 3, k = 0.5) # k regulates the distance between nodes
# weights = [G[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]
# nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='skyblue', font_weight='bold',  width=weights, pos=pos)

# we need to seperate the X,Y,Z coordinates for Plotly
# NOTE: spring_3D is a dictionary where the keys are 1,...,6
x_nodes= [spring_3D[key][0] for key in spring_3D.keys()] # x-coordinates of nodes
y_nodes = [spring_3D[key][1] for key in spring_3D.keys()] # y-coordinates
z_nodes = [spring_3D[key][2] for key in spring_3D.keys()] # z-coordinates

#we need to create lists that contain the starting and ending coordinates of each edge.
x_edges=[]
y_edges=[]
z_edges=[]

#create lists holding midpoints that we will use to anchor text
xtp = []
ytp = []
ztp = []

#need to fill these with all of the coordinates
for edge in edges:
    #format: [beginning,ending,None]
    x_coords = [spring_3D[edge[0]][0],spring_3D[edge[1]][0],None]
    x_edges += x_coords
    xtp.append(0.5*(spring_3D[edge[0]][0]+ spring_3D[edge[1]][0]))

    y_coords = [spring_3D[edge[0]][1],spring_3D[edge[1]][1],None]
    y_edges += y_coords
    ytp.append(0.5*(spring_3D[edge[0]][1]+ spring_3D[edge[1]][1]))

    z_coords = [spring_3D[edge[0]][2],spring_3D[edge[1]][2],None]
    z_edges += z_coords
    ztp.append(0.5*(spring_3D[edge[0]][2]+ spring_3D[edge[1]][2])) 


etext = [f'weight={w}' for w in edge_weights]

trace_weights = go.Scatter3d(x=xtp, y=ytp, z=ztp,
    mode='markers',
    marker =dict(color='rgb(125,125,125)', size=1), #set the same color as for the edge lines
    text = etext, hoverinfo='text')

#create a trace for the edges
trace_edges = go.Scatter3d(
    x=x_edges,
    y=y_edges,
    z=z_edges,
    mode='lines',
    line=dict(color='black', width=2),
    hoverinfo='none')

#create a trace for the nodes
trace_nodes = go.Scatter3d(
    x=x_nodes,
    y=y_nodes,
    z=z_nodes,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(symbol='circle',
            size=10,
            color='skyblue')
    )

#Include the traces we want to plot and create a figure
data = [trace_edges, trace_nodes, trace_weights]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great!! The only missing piece is the edges' weights

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I am not sure if that's a parameter that can be explicitly set in Plotly... but it looks like you can have the [weights display as hovertext](https://community.plotly.com/t/show-edge-weight-in-network-graph/26733)

Comment: Of course! I really appreciate the help in the first place. So it might be simpler than that. It looks like you just need to set `width=edge_weight` for each edge under `trace_edges`. I'm trying to figure out how to do it

Comment: And looks like I'll need to add labels as well. Missed that one in your code. I modified this line `x_nodes` to `x_nodes= [spring_3D[key][0] for key in spring_3D.keys()]` to allow any labels (otherwise it's fixed for 1-6)

Comment: It looks like the method used in the linked comment anchors the hover text at midpoints between the edges. I've updated my answer, and hopefully that's closer to what you're looking for

Comment: I think I was looking more for something along either what `networkx` does with the text (where it's inside the circle), or [this](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/)